# Definition of Service "/turtlebot/set_parameters"?

Tags: ros, python, turtlebot, parameters, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For my bachelors thesis I'm programming an iRobot Create using ROS Fuerte and the turtlebot_node package with Python. 
The Problem is that `~cmd_vel_timeout` is set to 0.6 Seconds by default and this is very annoying since I don't want to send it the same vector (if it hasn't changed) for moving every half second.
Using `rosnode info turtlebot` I've seen that there is a service called `/turtlebot/set_parameters` and I'd like to use this service in my Python program to change the value of `~cmd_vel_timeout`.
So here is my problem:
Where is the service `/turtlebot/set_parameters` defined so I can use it with `rospy.ServiceProxy(..)`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48656/definition-of-service-%22/turtlebot/set_parameters%22?/) by [mind4z](https://answers.ros.org/users/3395/mind4z/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2012-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find out where the service is defined using `rosservice type <srv>`.

Besides that, the setting of cmd_vel_timeout to 0.6s is very reasonable and in general should NOT be set very high. Resending the same velocity is the right thing to do!
The reason for that is safety. If the control program crashes/is stopped, you don't want the robot continuing to go with the last set velocity. I'd highly recommend not changing that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1